# What is a Universal Construction in Category Theory?

Tags: category-theory, universal-property

From pg. 59 of *Categories for the Working Mathematician*:

> Show that the construction of the polynomial ring $K[x]$ in an indeterminate $x$ over a commutative ring $K$ is a **universal construction.**

**Question:** What does the author mean by this bolded term?

For context: up to this point in the book, the author has already defined the notions of universal arrow, universal element, and universal property.

Is the author therefore just using the term **universal construction** as a synonym for the term **universal property** (or **universal X**, where **X** could be either **element** or **arrow**)?

Comment: If you are also interested in how to show this then have a look at the answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/531073/75923).

Answer (score 15):

A universal construction is simply a definition of an object as "the unique-up-to-isomorphism object satisfying a certain universal property". The name "construction" is a little misleading, because it's a *definition*: one still needs to show that the object actually exists, and that usually has to be done non-category-theoretically.

Comment: Formally speaking, when you say it's an "object", do you mean its an object in a comma category (or slice/coslice category)? That is, does the "object" encode both an object and a morphism, or just an object?

Comment: It need not be in a comma category: for example, a universal construction of an initial object can be stated as "the object $0$ such that for every object $A$, there is a unique arrow $0 \to A$", which doesn't involve a comma category explicitly.

Comment: In the setting of the initial object as a universal construction, what is the underlying slice/coslice/comma category? That is, I'm assuming what you are saying equates to $(0, f)$ is a universal arrow in some $(A, \mathcal{C})$ for some object $A$ in some category $\mathcal{C}$. If this is true, then what is $\mathcal{C}$ and $A$? What is $f$? Or am I totally confused?  :)

Comment: I ended up here after reading the paragraph about universal constructions from "Category Theory for Programmers" by Bartosz Milewski.
This answer helped me a lot, but I still miss a lot of contexts to fully understand it.
This resource clarified to me the meaning of "universal property" and its role in the universal construction thing. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/universal+construction
Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

The term "[universal construction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/universal+construction)" isn't that widely used in my experience, but it's pretty clearly a construction that is [characterized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterization_(mathematics)) by a universal property.  In general, as Patrick Stevens and the nLab page states, you actually have to make a real construction to show that *something* satisfies the characterization. In some formal/logical/type theoretic contexts, you can view this as providing rules for completely syntactic objects.  In effect, you are axiomatically assuming the existence of an object that satisfies the universal property.  In this case though, the exercise is to find a universal *property* which characterizes the polynomial ring construction.  A bit more colorfully, the exercise is to find the "essence" of the polynomial ring construction and present it in the form of a universal property.